# Basic C program does not display anything

Tags: c

What does my program not output anything.  I have tried other similar versions of solutions for project euler problem 1.  I don't need the answer I would just like to know why their is no output.  After I compile with gcc and execute the file it seems like is freezes with no output.  I have to ctrl-z to kill the program.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    /* Project Euler Problem 1 */

    int main()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 1000);
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0);
            {
                sum += i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `while(...);`, that semicolon. This is why I advocate the `while(...) {` style.

Comment: No ; in while statement

Comment: he means 'take the semicolon off the while'.

Comment: And take off the semi-color after the `if` statement

Comment: lecturers love tricking students with this

Comment: also as nobody has pointed it out yet, you are running and infinite loop because the body of the while is not executed due to the `;`. `i` is never incremented

Comment: I cannot see any of those problems you guys have commented/answered on.  It's almost like someone edited the question to make the whole set of question, comments and answers pointless and of no value to future visitors.

Comment: @kwa1977: Your edit made the answer and comments irrelevant. Don't do that.

Comment: *Basic debugging* would immediately have pointed out the problematic line. (Well, at least the first one.)

Comment: Got it I won't do that any more.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You are closing the `while` without doing any instruction by putting a semi-colon:

```
 while (i <= 1000);
```

You should drop the semicolon.

The same for the `if` instruction:

```
if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated it.